# Why does python shows UnboundLocalError: local variable 'w' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, function, datetime

```py
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
q = int(now.strftime('%I'))
w = int(now.strftime('%M'))

def correct_time(time_diff):

    if w < (120 - time_diff):
        q = q + 1 
        w = w + (time_diff - 60)
    else:
        q = q + 2 
        w = w + time_diff - 120

    return q, w

correct_time(105)

#gives the error - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'w' referenced before assignment
```

In the above code I imported datetime module and assigned two varibles q and w (as seen in lines 3 and 4 of code). But on calling the function 'correct_time()' the Jupyter notebook gives an **UnboundLocalError** message.

According to what I have seen while creating a function before, in python a function can use a variable called before and outside the function. Since the variables q and w have already been defined why won't it get recognized inside the function?

Comment: You're assigning a local `w` variable, and attempting to read from a global `w`. Since that doesn't make any sense, the Python interpreter assumes you're making an error, and wanted a local `w`, and says `UnboundLocalError`. If you want to use a global `w`, add the line `global w` to the start of the function.

Comment: ...but keep in mind that globals are generally Bad, and definitely code smell. Avoid them if possible (and here it appears like it is!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `correct_time`, you assign to `w` so it is defined as a local variable.

However, before you assign to `w`, you check `if w < (120 - time_diff):`

At this point, `w` is not bound to anything, which gives you that error. You should instead either

A. Define `q` and `w` inside `correct_time`, or
B. Parameterize `q` and `w` and pass it in in the function call like `correct_time(105, q, w)`